# Cannot find annotated custom JSF2 component in jar

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

We are migrating JSF1.2 to JSF2 application and I have bumped into a problem with custom components. We have a seperate jar with components, and in that jar I have this:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "Panel2")
public class Panel2 extends UIOutput { ... }
```

In my taglib under META-INF I have this:

```xml
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    id="mw">
    <namespace>http://www.ssss.be/jsf/mw</namespace>
    <composite-library-name>mw</composite-library-name>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>panel2</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>Panel2</component-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

After making a jar of this all and use it in my other project, I use the tag as follows:

```
xmlns:mw="http://www.ssss.be/jsf/mw"
```

And then:

```
<mw:panel2 />
```

But the result is unfortunately:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: Panel2 not found. at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1858)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1129)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- ensure that the JSF version in faces-config.xml is at least version 2
- ensure there isn't a `metadata-complete` attribute in faces-config.xml set to true.
- ensure that the class is either in `WEB-INF/classes`; or, if in a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`, that the jar contains a faces-config.xml (the spec doesn't require annotation scanning otherwise)
- ensure there isn't a `Panel2` component-type defined in an XML configuration file (this listing will take precedence)

See the [JSF 2 spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314); section 11.5.1.

Comment: Thanks! I simply forgot to upgrade the faces-config in my componentlib jar.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017504/facelet-tag-library-mechanism-does-not-work-as-expected). This post helped me a lot. Thanks.